# Retornando item do objeto de um array

Tags: php, laravel

Bom estou precisando percorrer um array e retornar uma propriedade do objeto daquele item em questão.

Meu array tem este formato:

[image: Arquivo mongodb array de links]

Tentei resolver isto com a seguinte função:

```
public function returnObjectByDayAndTrip($links, $trip, $dayOperation)
{
    $newArray = array_filter($links, function ($obj) use ($trip, $dayOperation) {
        if ($obj['trip'] == $trip && $obj['dayOperation'] === $dayOperation) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (isset($newArray[0])) {
        return $newArray[0]['url'];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

E para chamar ela uso:

```
$link->week = $this->returnObjectByDayAndTrip($links, $trip, 'week');
```

Onde $links é meu array da imagem, $trip é o dia que preciso pegar, e 'week' é o dia de operação que preciso pegar.

Meu erro acontece quando por exemplo o item é o [3] do array, quando é o primeiro tudo funciona mais apartir da posição [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5KOq.png) nada funciona mais.

Meu retorno com `var_dump` é

> object(stdClass)#632 (4) { ["week"]=> string(77) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-santa-ruth-em-dias-uteis" ["saturday"]=> NULL ["sunday"]=> NULL ["changeDestiny"]=> NULL }

Preciso retornar a url do objeto baseado nas particularidade passada para função. No meu array necessariamente terá apenas 1 items ou nenhum que satisfaz as informações informadas, ou seja sempre terá um resultado ou nenhum.

O retorno de todas vezes que chamei está assim:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#477 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5b3f74ad6ae83d00223504e8" } ["url"]=> string(77) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-santa-ruth-em-dias-uteis" ["dayOperation"]=> string(4) "week" ["trip"]=> string(5) "tripA" } } 

array(1) { [2]=> array(4) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#479 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5b3f74ad6ae83d00223504e6" } ["url"]=> string(73) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-santa-ruth-no-sabado" ["dayOperation"]=> string(8) "saturday" ["trip"]=> string(5) "tripA" } } 

array(1) { [4]=> array(4) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#481 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5b3f74ad6ae83d00223504e4" } ["url"]=> string(74) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-santa-ruth-no-domingo" ["dayOperation"]=> string(6) "sunday" ["trip"]=> string(5) "tripA" } } 

array(1) { [1]=> array(4) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#478 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5b3f74ad6ae83d00223504e7" } ["url"]=> string(77) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-bela-vista-em-dias-uteis" ["dayOperation"]=> string(4) "week" ["trip"]=> string(5) "tripB" } }
```

Comment: Não é no `return` o problema? se não tem que retornar o objeto?

Comment: O array_filter não exige true ou false ? Para que retorne aquela posição ? Pergunto porque em javascript funciona desta maneira perfeitamente.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta @VirgilioNovic você pode ver que ele retorna os objetos mas observe que cada objeto está em uma posição do array, todos eles tem 1 posição mais esta posição esta em diferentes lugares.

Comment: Você precisa trazer os dados de que forma?: isso que eu não entendi?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic no caso preciso trazer apenas url que é um item do objeto.

Comment: Nesse resultado pode ter duplicação? ou só apenas um item?

Comment: Não tem duplicação, no momento de criar cuidei para que não houves-se ou seja, tem apenas um combo de cada um week, tripa, tripb, saturday, tripa, tripb, sunday, tripa, tripb

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver utilizando o `current()` ele retorna a primeira posição de um array então ficou desta maneira:

```
public function returnObjectByDayAndTrip($links, $trip, $dayOperation)
{
    $newArray = array_filter($links, function ($obj) use ($trip, $dayOperation) {
        if ($obj['trip'] == $trip && $obj['dayOperation'] === $dayOperation) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });


    if (count($newArray) >= 1) {
        return current($newArray)['url'];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Provavelmente existe uma maneira melhor de fazer, e até aceito este novos métodos porém desta forma solucionou meu problema. O ideal neste caso é uma junção com `array_map` e `array_filter` para ficar robusto.